# Expressing an OR constraint in linear programming

Tags: constraints, linear-programming

I have a floating-point variable `x` in a linear program which shall be either `0` or between two constants `CONSTANT_A` and `CONSTANT_B`:

`LP.addConstraint(x == 0 OR CONSTANT_A <= x <= CONSTANT_B)`

Of course there is no such thing as an explicit `OR` in linear programming. Is there a way to express this constraint?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular language/framework, or is this just a math question?

Comment: It's not about a particular language or framework. If there is a solution to this problem it should be possible to express this constraint in any language/LP framework, shouldn't it?

Comment: Apart from the given answer, this is an example of section *7.1:  A variable taking discontinuous values* in [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf).

Comment: This is called a `semi-continuous variable`. Most MIP solvers can handle this directly. It is also possible to use a binary to model this.  .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So let's assume you want the constraint:

```
x == 0 OR 1 <= x <= 2
```

It is clear that the feasible region of your linear program is not convex, since x=0 and x=1 are both feasible, but no proper convex combination is feasible. As a result, it is provably impossible to model this with a linear program.

That being said, it is easy to model this if you introduce a binary decision variable y, which takes value 1 if we are in the range and 0 if we are fixed to 0. Then you can model the following:

```
y <= x <= 2*y
y binary
```

or, in your fully general case:

```
y*CONSTANT_A <= x <= y*CONSTANT_B
y binary
```