# MIP (mixed integer problem) Build Constraint with OR

Tags: python, linear-programming, constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming, coin-or-cbc

I have an **MIP** where I want to assign at least two variables (binary) from the same location.

How to implement the `or` in this case. I want something like this:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 >= 2 or
x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 >= 2 or
x10 + x11 + x12 >= 2
```

`x1,...,x12` are binary variables.

How could it be implemented?

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987517/expressing-an-or-constraint-in-linear-programming) but could not work it out to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 >= 2⋅δ1
x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 >= 2⋅δ2
x10 + x11 + x12 >= 2⋅δ3
δ1+δ2+δ3 = 1 
δ1,δ2,δ3 ∈ {0,1}
```

If you want, you can replace `δ1+δ2+δ3=1` by `δ1+δ2+δ3>=1`.